# De sql a eloquent de laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Llevo horas tratando de transformar lo siguiente a eloquent ¿Alguien tiene algún idea?
El modelo es 'Post' y la tabla es 'posts', estoy usando laravel 8.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE visible=1 AND private=0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

Intentos fallidos:

```
Post::all()->sortBy("RAND()")->where("visible", "=", 1)->where("private", "=", 0);

Post::all()->where("visible", "=", 1)->where("private", "=", 0)->sortBy("RAND()")
```

Por alguna razon tampoco tengo acceso a metodos como where, limit, inRandomOrder, etc, solo all().

Comment: - Post::all()->sortBy("RAND()")->where("visible", "=", 1)->where("private", "=", 0);

Comment: Supuestamente hay métodos como Post::where, select o find, pero el unico al que puedo acceder es a "all()".

Comment: También intente con 
Post::all()->where("visible", "=", 1)->where("private", "=", 0)->sortBy("RAND()")
Pero su resultado es estatico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta es muy simple en si, puede quedar de esta forma:

```
Post::whereVisible(1)->wherePrivate(0)->inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
```

Usamos:

Al query builder para:

- Establecer un [`limit`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#limit-and-offset) de la cantidad de resultados
- Se puede usar el método [`orderByRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#orderbyraw) para pasar el nombre de la función `RAND` que deseas emplear para el *ordenamiento*, pero se hace un tanto *innecesario* desde el momento que también tenemos a nuestro alcance al método [`inRandomOrder`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#random-ordering) que en este caso nos dará el mismo resultado.

Ahora (*aunque yo me quedaría con la primer opción*), si quieres establecer filtros sobre los modelos obtenidos gracias a `all` pudieras tratar de esta manera:

```
Post::all()->where("visible", 1)
           ->where("private", 0)
           ->shuffle()
           ->take(10);
```

Ahora debes tener presente que:

- En este segundo ejemplo estamos operando pero sobre la colección resultante
- Te funcionan métodos como `where` y `sortBy` pues las colecciones los tienen disponibles, aquí [puedes leer dichos métodos](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods)
- Dado el punto anterior entonces es perfectamente normal que no tengas alcance dentro de esta colección a métodos como `inRandomOrder()`, en cambio dispones de:

  - `random` retorna un solo elemento de manera aleatoria
  - `shuffle` retorna de manera aleatoria los elementos de una colección

Anexo a lo anterior debes tener en claro lo que una consulta te retorna para lograr diferenciarlas y en consecuencia saber que métodos podrás o no aplicar.

- Ejemplo con `all()` el retorno es una:

  ```
  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
  ```
- Ejemplo con `Modelo::whereAlgo(......);`

  ```
  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
  ```

Comment: No conocía sobre esa sintaxis para el whereCampo, al parecer esas sentencias (whereVisible, wherePrivate) me dan acceso a "inRandomOrder" y "limit", ya que antes estaba intentando acceder desde ::all() y me rechazaba esos métodos de limit y inRamdonOrder (No los reconocía).
Gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Una pequeña consulta ¿Para que se reconozca esos métodos es necesario ejecutar algún comando? Leí algo por ahí sobre "ide-helper" (php artisan ide-helper:generate) pero parece que ya no viene con laravel. Al intentar autocompletar completar métodos como inRamdonOrder no es reconocido.

Comment: Respecto a tu última pregunta no te sabría decir, yo jamás he ejecutado dicho método, por otro lado he editado mi respuesta te recomiendo checarla @FabrizioPiminchumo

Comment: De ser posible, podría revisar la siguiente pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/433116/orderby-provoca-un-doble-sentencia-desc-asc Gracias @BetaM