# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'desc' in 'order clause'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Actualmente estoy usando lo siguiente: (Mi intento por mostrar de forma descendente)

```
Post::whereVisible(1)->wherePrivate(0)->OrderBy("desc")->limit(16)->get();
```

Pero devuelve el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'desc' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `visible` = 1 and `private` = 0 order by `desc` asc limit 16)
```

En la parte del order by se puede observar que tiene el "desc" pero al costado el "asc". ¿El desc no deberia remplazar al asc?

Adicionalmente tambien intente con:

```
Post::whereVisible(1)->wherePrivate(0)->sortByDesc()->limit(16)->get();
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::sortByDesc()
```

De igual forma lo intente con este:

```
Post::whereVisible(1)->wherePrivate(0)->sortDesc()->limit(16)->get()
```

Pero devuelve el siguien teerror:

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::sortDesc()
```

Estos últimos dos métodos lo saque de la documentación de que anteriormente me sugieran seguir para crear sus consultas. [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) (Estoy usando laravel 8)

Comment: El error es por que el método `orderBy` debe recibir el nombre de la columna por la cual quieres hacer el ordenamiento y opcionalmente si es asc o desc, ya que por default es `asc`, por eso te marca el error ya que esta tratando de localizar en tu tabla posts una columna llamada desc la cual claramente no existe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con respecto del primer error, se debe a que el método `orderBy` del *query builder* que puedes localizar en:

```
app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php
```

Espera:

- Un argumento obligatorio para indicar el nombre de la columna por la cual se hará el ordenamiento
- Un argumento opcional que indica que tipo de ordenamiento se desea aplicar (*por default se aplica `asc`*)

Luego entonces al solo recibir el string `desc` lo esta *interpretando* como el nombre de la columna por la cual debe realizar el ordenamiento.

Para corregir dicho error que se te presenta, alcanza con que hagas lo siguiente:

```
......orderBy('columnaNombre', 'desc')......
```

**Referencia**

- [ordenamiento](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#ordering)

Con respecto del segundo error, se genera debido a que:

- El método `sortByDesc` es perteneciente a la clase *Collection* que puedes localizar en:

  ```
  app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php
  ```

Por lo tanto es perfectamente normal que cuando trabajas con el *Query Builder* te indique que no se encuentre disponible dicho método por que de hecho no existe en la clase Builder